# Is it possible for a particle to cross the event horizon of a black hole via traveling back in time?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, time-travel

> Let us suppose we have a particle that is near the event horizon of a black hole.
> The Shroedinger equation for particle without interacting with itself in a gravitational field is given as:
> $$
> i \hbar \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} = (-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2  + V(x)) \Psi
> $$
> Where $\Psi(x,t)$ is the time dependant wavefunction.

Mathematicaly, if I am not mistaken, there is a probabilty that the particle is everywhere in the universe (for $t \rightarrow \infty)$. 
This means that in theory it could have crossed the event horizon of the black hole. 
My question is: 
Is it reasonable to assume that the only way for that to have happened is if the particle traveled back in time at a point in time where there did not exist a horizon and thus enable given particle to have crossed the space ? 
(My reasoning is inspired behind the idea of the [One-electron univerese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-electron_universe))
[image]

Comment: @safesphere what if I am only interested at x(t´) ?

Comment: There are two things which I'm feeling kinda off. First I really don't think Schrodinger equation should be applied instead full machinery of QFT needs to be used my reason the same one given by Coleman about the failure of one particle qm. Second are you talking about 1+1 case cause otherwise I can reach marked point by going around E.H.?